# Keyboard is not dismissing inside the UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have tried many solutions, but so far no luck. Can anyone tell me what am I missing. here is my code sample.
**This app is using landscape view of the iPhone (Testing in simulator)** (When display keyboard, it covers the alert view's buttons)

```
func ShowAlert() {
    let InputAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "If many values input with (,)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
    InputAlert.view.autoresizesSubviews = true
    
    let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leadConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: InputAlert.view!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0)

    let trailConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: InputAlert.view!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0)

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: InputAlert.view!, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -64.0)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: InputAlert.view!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64.0)
    
    textView.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
    InputAlert.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    InputAlert.view.addSubview(textView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadConstraint, trailConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
    
    
    InputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        print("Canceled")
    }))
    
    beaconInputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        let insertedId = textView.text
        print(insertedId)
    }))
    
    self.present(InputAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is the Extension :

```
extension UIViewController {
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first

    if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        topController.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to dismiss the keyboard?  And under what class are you writing ShowAlert()?

Comment: After I tapped besides the alert view. I have tried UITapGestureRecognizer, but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First you can create extension of UIViewController like below and then you can use extension's method in ViewDidLoad() method of controller where you want to use.

```
extension UIViewController {
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false            
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have already tried that one also, unfortunately it didn't work. It works on viewController but not in alertViewController with UITextView.